# Casper.js unable to open JSON file when activated through python script

Tags: python, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a CasperJS script that opens a JSON file of search terms and parses a page looking for them. It works fine when I run it from the command line.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var fs = require('fs')
var names = fs.read('/var/www/html/tracker/names.json');
...
```

But when I try to run it through a shell script using Python, it has difficulty reading the JSON file. `fs.read` returns `""`.

The Python script:

```
app = subprocess.Popen("/usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/html/tracker/scraper.js", shell=True)
app.wait()
out, errs = app.communicate()
```

Comment: To deepen the mystery, the subprocess reads names.json fine when it's saved as names.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Naturally, my own boneheaded mistake.

Didn't make this clear in the question, but the Python script first prepares `names.json` before running the scraper through a subprocess. So if we add a little bit to the code snippet shown above:

```
# Save JSON file
f = open('names.json', 'w')
f.write( json.dumps(json_ready, sort_keys=True, indent=4) )

# Query scraper
app = subprocess.Popen("/usr/local/bin/casperjs /var/www/html/tracker/scraper.js", shell=True)
app.wait()
out, errs = app.communicate()
```

The problem? I forgot to close `f`.

```
# Save JSON file
f = open('names.json', 'w')
f.write( json.dumps(json_ready, sort_keys=True, indent=4) )
f.close()
```